# Реализация компонента вставки записи в бд в yii2

Tags: база-данных, yii2, activerecord, компоненты

На фреймворке Yii2 Необходимо реализовать свой компонент, который принимает несколько параметров и заносит их в базу данных. Как это реализовать?(Проблема- я не знаю как использовать activeRecord в данной ситуации)

Моя модель:

```
class Articles extends ActiveRecord 
{ 

  public static function tableName() { 
    return 'med_articles'; 
  } 

  public function getCategory() { 
    return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['cat_id' => 'cat_id']); 
  } 

}
```

Comment: а как вы его используете в другой ситуации? Вы хотя бы модель опишите.. она у Вас есть? Какие параметра?

Comment: Модель:
class Articles extends ActiveRecord
{
   
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'med_articles';
    }
    public function getCategory(){
        return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['cat_id' => 'cat_id']);
    }
} 
Метод компонента принимает параметры: название статьи и описание. Необходимо чтобы компонент,приняв параметры, вставлял их в эту таблицу

Comment: Читайте документацию Yii2, там нужно большинство что вам нужно. А про то что не знаете - пишите здесь, конкретные вопросы про конкретные проблемы.

Comment: @Сергей, в вопросе всё это нужно описысать. Как Вам поомгать люди будут?

Comment: Я совсем новичок в этом деле) Непременно учту

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, я правильно понимаю, что нужно просто use-ать модель таблицы в классе своего компонента, и запросы делать точно также, как и в контроллерах?

Comment: Можно и так, только учтите что в Yii2 компоненты это наследующие от Component, а не ActiveRecord, поэтому с вашей формулировкой вопроса ответ будет - класс, наследующиц от Component должен использовать ActiveRecord при создании.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто. Создаёте компонент в папке components. Если используете шаблон Advanced - путь до папки будет `common/components`, если шаблон Basic - создайте в корне проекта папку `components`.

Код примерно такой:

```
<?php

namespace [путь до папки components];

use [путь до модели]/Articles;

class ArticleComponent extends \Yii\Base\Component
{
    public function create($parametrOne, $parametrTwo)
    {
        $article = new Articles();
        $article->parametr_one = $parametrOne;
        $article->parametr_two = $parametrTwo;

        return $article->save();
    }
}
```

Далее в конфиге сайта подключаем наш компонент в разделе `'components'`

```
'components' => [
    ...
    'article' => [
        'class' => '[namespace компонента]\ArticleComponent'
    ],
    ...
]
```

Теперь его можно использовать где угодно на Вашем сайте. Например вот так:

`Yii::$app->article->create('parametr1', 'parametr2');`